# Line integrals of $\frac{1}{z^2}$ and $\frac{e^z}{z}$ without calculations.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have learned that :

1) if $f$, a holomorphic function on $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, open and simply connected, then $f$ has a holomorphic antiderivative on $U$

2) if $f$, a holomorphic function on $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ has a holomorphic antiderivative on $U$, then for $\gamma\subset U$ a loop, $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$

If I consider $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma(t)=2+e^{it}$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z}dz=0$, since $\displaystyle\frac{e^z}{z}$ is holomorphic on $D(2,2)$, which is open and simply connected (so we have (1)), and $\gamma\subset D(2,2)$ (so we have (2)).

If I consider $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to cos(t)+2isin(t)$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz=0$ because $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{z}$ is the antiderivative of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z^2}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and it's holomorphic.

Is this correct or did I miss a condition ?

Comment: $1/z^2$ is not analytic in any region that contains $z=0$.  The ellipse that is described by $z(t)=\cos t+i 2\sin t$, encompasses a region that contains $z=0$.   However, $\oint_{\gamma} 1/z^2 dz=0$.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that $1/z^2$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Do you mean that I have to apply another theorem ? Why doesn't this one work, should I understand "$\gamma\subset U$" as in, $\gamma$ and its interior ?

Comment: $\oint_{\gamma} 1/z^2 dz=0$, but not because it is analytic, except for $z=0$.  For example, $1/z$ is also analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}
$, but $\oint_{\gamma} 1/z dz =2\pi i$

Comment: Yes, because $1/z$ does not have a holomorphic antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, but $1/z^2$ does.

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't understand your comments. The OP clearly gave a valid reason for why the integral over the ellipse equals zero.

Comment: @zhw Note that the contour $\gamma$ encircles $z=0$.

Comment: That doesn't matter if the integrand has an antiderivative in $\mathbb {C} \setminus \{0\}$, which $1/z^2$ does, as the OP noted.